# Reboot Raspberry Pi if service not running

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, cron

I am running Bitorrent Sync from my Raspberry Pi. Very occasionally it will- for some reason- go offline. I am trying to run [a script from crontab that will check the connection](http://weworkweplay.com/play/rebooting-the-raspberry-pi-when-it-loses-wireless-connection-wifi/) but I also want to check the status of the btsync service (`sudo service btsync status`). How can I put this in a script that will run from Crontab, look at the output, and initiate a reboot if anything other than "running"?

Comment: Why reboot? Just have the script restart the service.

Comment: Because it's easier and more fool-proof to just reboot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could follow the same steps as you do for checkwifi.sh, but make it checkbtsync.sh

Something along these lines should work:

```
#!/bin/sh    
btsyncResult=$(sudo service btsync status)

if [[ $btsyncResult != *"is running"* ]]
then
    sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now
fi
```

Theoretically, that will take the result of your btsync status command and store it in the variable as text. if the text doesn't contain the word 'running' it shuts down. The rest is just like the checkwifi steps at the link you mentioned:

store it at /usr/local/bin/checkbtsync.sh

then run

```
sudo chmod 775 /usr/local/bin/checkbtsync.sh
```

Then crontab gets this new line:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/sudo -H /usr/local/bin/checkbtsync.sh >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: This looks good, thank you. Could you please explain the last line; what does the `-H` and the `/dev/null 2>&1` do? I am also finding it hard to test this as my attempts to write to a log file are failing...

Comment: from the sudo man page: <br/><br/>

The -H (HOME) option requests that the security policy set the HOME environment variable to the home directory of the target user (root by default) as specified by the password database. Depending on the policy, this may be the default behavior.
<br/><br/>
Probably unnecessary, but may help sudo find the script you're running.
<br/><br/>
The > /dev/nul 2>&1 sends the output "nowhere," making it quiet. Also probably unnecessary. 

I just borrowed both from the checkwifi tutorial you shared.

Comment: Thanks. However there seems to be a problem with your code unless I'm missing something; I am getting the error `btsyncResult: command not found`?

Comment: ok, the problem seems to be the spaces, so it should be `btsyncResult=$(sudo service btsync status)`. Works great now, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check if process is running, with `ps aux`. Name the below script as **btsync_reboot.sh** and `chown` it to user running cron.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "check service $(date)" >> /var/log/btsync-check.log
ps auxw | grep btsync | grep -v grep > /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
        echo "rebooting at $(date)" >> /var/log/btsync-reboot.log
        reboot now >> /var/log/btsync-reboot.log
else 
        echo "btsync is running"  >> /var/log/btsync-check.log
fi
```

Cron expression: `* * * * * sh /path/to/btsync-reboot.sh`

Comment: This is a reasonable answer, however `ps aux` checks the process, not the actual status of the service. For example, manually stopping btsync with `sudo service btsync stop` and running this script still returns "btsync is running". Checking the the state of the process is no bad thing though as an extra check.